# how to convert a polar coordinate matrix into cartesian matrice in matlab?

Tags: matlab

how to convert a polar coordinate matrix into Cartesian matrix in Matlab?

I have a polar coordinate matrix and I need to transform into Cartesian coordinate matrix.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you mean? You have a matrix with polar coordinates? Any reason [`pol2cart`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pol2cart.html) does not work for you? Also, please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did you even try a simple Google search before asking your question?  http://www.google.com/?q=polar%20to%20cartesian%20matlab

Comment: I assume that you ask some kind of question like "What function should I use in Matlab" since I guess you know the mathematical relationship. However, from the website: **"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it. "**

Answer (score 2):

I assume you mean polar in 2d? (angle, radius)

Let `A` be the matrix with the angles, `R` the matrix with the raddii. Then you can simply calculate

```
X = cos(A).*R
Y = sin(A).*R
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a matrix `P`, containing rows of coordinates, with angle `theta` in the first column and radius `rho` in the second column, then

```
[X, Y] = pol2cart(P(:, 1), P(:, 2));
```

gives you cartesian coordinates.